# regular expression for 9999.9999 or 9999 or 9999:9999

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I want regular expression for 0000.0000-9999.9999 or 0000-9999 or 0000:0000-9999:9999.

could it be :  `/^(\d{4}$\.\d{4}$)|(\d{4}$)|(\d{4}$\:\d{4}$)/` ?
please guide

Comment: i don't want to allow "-" & any other character also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` marks the end of line like `^` marks the beginning of it, so `/^(\d{4}$\.\d{4}$)|(\d{4}$)|(\d{4}$\:\d{4}$)/` is wrong.

I would try:

```
/^(\d{4}\.\d{4})|(\d{4})|(\d{4}\:\d{4})$/
```

instead.

You can also make the second part optional and allow for `.` and `:` if it is present:

```
/^\d{4}([\.:]\d{4})?$/
```

(I'm more a Perl regex man, but it should work for JavaScript as well)

Comment: @MayP: The expression provided is perfectly fine in JavaScript. Btw, there is no need to escape the `.` inside the character group.

Comment: @MayP: AFAIK it should work with JavaScript as well. I can't test it just now.

Comment: @Felix: Thanks, I thought so about the `.` but kept the ``\`` just to be on the safe side :-)

Comment: @Martin Scharrer:how could i allow 0-9999?

Comment: @MayP: Should be possible using `\d{1,4}` instead of `\d{4}`.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer:please give me complete RegExp for this

Comment: I could able to allow 0 or 0.0 or 100.20 or 1000 or 0.99, please help

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for this one

```
^\d{4}(?:([.:])\d{4})?(?:-\d{4}(?:\1\d{4})?)?$
```

Explanation

```
^               # start-of-string
\d{4}           # four digits
(?:             # non-capturing group
  ([.:])        #   delimiter char (store in group 1)
  \d{4}         #   four digits
)?              # end group, make optional
(?:             # non-capturing group
  -             #   a dash
  \d{4}         #   four digits
  (?:\1\d{4})?  #   whatever group 1 was plus four digits (optional)
)?              # end group, make optional
$               # end-of-string
```

This still allows `0000-9999.9999`. You could check for this special case by evaluating string length after a successful match (i.e., must be 4, 9 or 19).

Alternatively, you can prepend the regex with `(?=.{4}$|.{9}$|.{19}$)`.

Comment: This doesn't handle `0000-9999`.

Comment: @lepple: I'm aware that the `-` should not be matched. With `0000-9999` I meant the range from `0000` till `9999`, i.e. any four digit combination.

Comment: Last capturing group could be non-capturing.

Comment: @Qtax: Yes. I'll add that as well. @Martin: fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
/[0-9]{4}((\.|-|:)?[0-9]{0|4})?/
```

Comment: This would allow `0000:` or `0000:0` as well, wouldn't it?